# inApp-Purchases cannot load products on jailbroken devices

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, jailbreak

I am using in-app purchases module of [raywenderlich](http://www.raywenderlich.com/21081/introduction-to-in-app-purchases-in-ios-6-tutorial) to help me doing purchases, my code is working really fine on non jailbroken devices. In jailbroken devices, the products don't appear and I cannot debug to see the problem. Has anybody be confronted with such issue? Thanks.

Comment: make sure there's no IAP tweaks like IAPCracker, IAPFree, LocalAPStore installed on the device.

Comment: People wont need IAP on jailbroken devices. They are just going to pirate your app.  TBH do not develop for jail broken devices.

Comment: How do you even get paid for IAP on apps that are not from the Apple store?